# How do I check out a file in Sharepoint 2007 using either a remote service or HTTP call?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2007, rpc

I can copy a file up to the Sharepoint archive using:

_vti_bin/Copy.asmx.CopyIntoItems

but if the file already exists it insists that I check it out.  Yet I cannot find a way of doing this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CheckOutFile`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.checkoutfile%28office.12%29.aspx

`CheckInFile`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.checkinfile%28office.12%29.aspx